# Borders of relative positioned table cells. IE displaying issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, border, css-tables

I have a trouble with setting borders for table cells which have relative position style: [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/GaTHZ/3/)

```
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid green;
    position: relative;
}
```

It looks ok in FF and Chrome:
[image]

But in IE i see doubled cell borders:
[image]

This doubled borders appears only if td relative positioned.

I know as workaround it is possible to remove border from table cell and put additional div with border inside of table cell.
But maybe there is another way to solve this issue in IE?

**EDIT:**
I managed to display borders combining cells and table border styles:
http://jsfiddle.net/GaTHZ/4/

Comment: Why are the cells positioned relatively?

Comment: because there are several absolute positioned div inside of cell.

Answer (score 1):

This will solve it. Worked in IE and Chrome.

```
 table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        margin-right:30px;
        margin-left:30px;
        border-right: 1px solid green;
        border-bottom: 1px solid green;
       }

    td {
           border-left: 1px solid green;
           border-top: 1px solid green;
           width: 200px;
           height: 35px;
           position: relative;
       }​
```

Comment: Yes, i did it the same way a little bit earlier. But anyway it is not exactly what i need :(